# VB6 String Contains URL using regular expressions

Tags: regex, string, vb6

I need to write code that will read a string and if it contains any part of a website address to remove html tags that surround it. Currently the string looks like the following:

The String causing the issue**This is a test string to show you what the issue is at**  **www.stackoverflow.com**

Any part of the web address would include:

.com, .ca, etc as well as www, http://, https://,

The output of the string is

**This is a test string to show you what the issue is at (Extra Space here)www.stackoverflow.com**

Below is the code that i have tried to get it to work. I created a boolean flag and if its true i want it to do other logic which I haven't written yet

```
Dim rex As RegExp
Set rex = New RegExp
Dim urlFlag As Boolean

rex.Pattern = "(http|https)://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?"

If rex.Test(str_Temp) Then
    urlFlag = True
Else
    urlFlag = False
End If
```

The output is always returning false meaning the pattern isn't working. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? If you have then please post it so someone can't point out your mistake instead of just asking for someone to write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone with a difference approach. Website address only start with www., http://, and https://. I created an array and I loop through the array and if the value of index i is in the str_temp the replace the text and it worked